# Retrieving values from DB to Label in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created an Entity Framework application to retrieve Database values but i want to show them in individual labels instead of a gridview??

```
EmployEntities2 fd = new EmployEntities2();
int idToupdate = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
  var jj = (from bn in fd.Contacts
              where bn.Id == idToupdate
              select bn);

  GridView1.DataSource = jj;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Show your work..

Comment: Without more information, the only help we can give is: use the [Label.Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0cs4xb3d.aspx) property.

Comment: People who down vote can you tell me what the problem is?? So people who down vote without a reason can answer me here as it degrades the questioner.

Comment: I dont know why i am no longer post the questions?? Because of these down votes?? Then what to do here??

Answer (score 0):

Established a connection

`SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("CONNECTION_STRING);`
`SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();`
and then,

`cmd.CommandText = "select * from table where Condition ;`
`cmd.Connection = con`

`Label1.text = ((string)cmd.ExecuteScalar());`

Try this one..

Answer (score 0):

You should use SQLDataReader class. Base on what type of data you have in structure you should call a different method of the SQLDataReader object. For example, if you need to retrieve an integer value and display it in a label, this is the code sinppet to do it:

```
string queryString = "SELECT integer_value FROM table_name";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    connection.open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        label1.Text = reader.getSqlInt32(0).ToString();
    }
    reader.close();
}
```

This is the best I can do since you didn't provide additional info.
Check out this link for info on SqlDataReader class: [SqlDataReader reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx)

Comment: I know about this classic way but i want to do this with entity framework.

Comment: `foreach(var bn in jj) { // do something with bn }`? For example `label1.Text = bn.Id;`, but that would overwrite the text every time and only display the `Id` of the last `bn`, so you might want to filter out a specific `bn` or create labels for every `bn` or whatever.